# why listener defined in a subclass seems that aren't defined

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a class that contains has a private member a combobox and extended CostomComponet as:

```
class TelefonoWidgetView extends CustomComponent {

private ComboBox comboRecTel;

private VerticalLayout recTelLayout(){

comboRecTel = new ComboBox();
comboRecTel.addValueChangeListener(new ValueChangeListener() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
             //do something

     }
}
```

Now in another class I need to use that class (that I cannot modify) and have a Listener on the combobox; How I can do that?

Let say my new class is WidgetView, and is defined as

```
WidgetView {

private TelefonoWidgetView tel;

private void metho1(){
    tel.addListener(new com.vaadin.ui.Component.Listener() {

            
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void componentEvent(Event event) {
                    System.out.println( " scatto addListener su tel : ");
                    
                }
            });

    }
  }
```

when I click on the combobox, I cannot see "scatto addListener su tel" on my console even if it compile correctly, It seems that the Listener has not been defined, while it is there!!

I know that I can create a combobox by myself but in the class TelefonoWidgetView there are other staff that I cannot copied;

I ve also tryed to put addDetachListener(new DetachListener(), addAttachListener(new AttachListener(),addContextClickListener(new ContextClickListener()

but no one is able to intercept the value change in the combobox

thanks a lot

Comment: I am quite out of the loop with V7, but I'd be really surprised if
adding any events on the outer object would have any consequences for an
unrelated inner object.  If you are desperate and _really_ can not
change your view there, I'd go with reflection directly for the private
combobox.

Comment: what do you mean with going with reflection?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java reflections API to access `comboRecTel` even though it is `private`.

```
Field privateField = TelefonoWidgetView.class.getDeclaredField("comboRecTel");
privateField.setAccessible(true);
ComboBox comboRecTel = (ComboBox) privateField.get(tel);
// then add your new custom listener here
comboRecTel.addValueChangeListener(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you can edit the `TelefonoWidgetView` class.
You can add a public method in your `TelefonoWidgetView` which accepts a `ValueChangeListener` and passes it on to the combobox like this:

```
// I use newer vaadin versions, so please excuse any errors in my syntax
class TelefonoWidgetView extends CustomComponent {

    private ComboBox comboRecTel;

    public TelefonoWidgetView(){
        comboRecTel = new ComboBox();
        ...
        addComponent(comboRecTel);
    }

    public void addTelValueChangeListener(ValueChangeListener valueChangeListener) {
        this.comboRecTel.addValueChangeListener(valueChangeListener);
    }
}

public class WidgetView {

    private TelefonoWidgetView tel;

    public WidgetView() {
        tel = new TelefornoWidgetView();
        addComponent(tel);
        metho1();
    }

    private void metho1(){
        tel.addTelValueChangeListener(new ValueChangeListener() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
                System.out.println( " scatto addListener su tel : "+event.getValue());
            }
        });
    }
```